# How to get list of elements from SVG?

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I want to get list of elements separately from SVG. To achieve this I need to get `android:pathData` for each element by parsing SVG. I found similar approach to get those data on web in http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/.

And also I tried with [SVG rendering library for Android](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/svg_implementation_details.html) but it returns drawable vector and cannot identify elements. I want to make fillable drawable vector in my canvas. How I achieve this?

Comment: You mean that you want to parse the svg file contents. If it is yes then let me know from where are you receiving this svg file and is it android converted svg file?

Comment: @AnuragSingh Kept SVG files in assets folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to make fillable drawable vector in my canvas"?  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Does [this tutorial](http://www.curious-creature.com/2013/12/21/android-recipe-4-path-tracing/) help you)?  It shows how to capture path data from AndroidSVG using a custom Canvas object.